# Action Script 3. How to remember last object x coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, history

I'm creating a flash game where objects are falling from the sky and the player needs to destroy them by clicking on them. But I have a problem, sometimes they spawning one on top of each other.
Here is an example what I mean:

[image: wrong spawn]

Objects should be spawned near other, but not one on other.

Here is my constant vars:

```
public static const GRAVITY:Number = 3;
public static const HIT_TOLERANCE:Number = 50;  

//Powerup
public static const APPLE_END_Y:Number = 640;
public static const APPLE_SPAWN_CHANCE:Number = 0.02; //per frame per second
public static const APPLE_START_Y:Number = 110;
public static const APPLE_SPAWN_START_X:Number = 50;
public static const APPLE_SPAWN_END_X:Number = 500;

//Scoring
public static const PLAYER_START_SCORE:Number = 0;
public static const SCORE_PER_APPLE:Number = 10;
```

Here is part of code where objects spawning:

```
private function update(evt:Event)
{

    //Spawn new apples
    if (Math.random() < randomChance)
    {
        //spawn x  coordinates
        var newPirmas = new Pirmas();
        newPirmas.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
        var newAntras = new Antras();
        newAntras.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
        var newTrecias = new Trecias();
        newTrecias.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
        var newApple = new Apple();
        newApple.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
        //spawn y coordinates
        newPirmas.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
        newAntras.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
        newTrecias.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
        newApple.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;

        newPirmas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        newAntras.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        newTrecias.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        newApple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

        itemsToSpawn.push(newPirmas, newAntras, newTrecias, newApple);
    }   
}
```

As someone said: `As for making sure they don't overlap, you can keep a history of their spawn points, and change how you get their random X value. Just iterate through the array of previous X values, and make sure the new one isn't within (oldX + (width/2)).`

But I can't make It successfully, could you help me with keeping history of their spawn points? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
var t:Array = [];
t[0] = [APPLE_SPAWN_START_X, APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + APPLE_WIDTH/2];
```

t will keep the available intervals the you can generate new apple.
In the start time, there is no apple, and the t has only one interval, the starX of the interval is APPLE_SPAWN_START_X, the endX of the interval is APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + APP_WIDTH/2.

where you want to generate a new apple, you would find a availble interval in t, if we find the interval as mInterval(the interval could put in the apple, means endX - starX >= APPLE_WIDTH), then we could generate your new apple.

We just need to change the lines in you update function like

```
newPirmas.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
```

Instead

```
newPirmas.x = mInterval[0] + Math.random()*APPLE_WIDTH;
```

When we set newPirmas.x, we have break the mInterval and generate two new interval,
the values are [mInterval[0],newPirmas.x] and []newPirmas.x +  APPLE_WIDTH, mInterval[0]],
so we need to delete the mInterval in t and put the two new intervals into t.

```
    /**
     * 
     * @return index of available interval in target array
     */
    public static function findAvailInterval(target:Array, appleWidth:int):int {

        if (target == null || target.length == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        var endX:int = 0;
        var startX:int = 0;

        var length:int = target.length;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < length; i++) {

            var temp:Array = target[i] as Array;

            if (temp == null || temp.length < 2) {
                return -1;
            }

            startX = temp[0];
            endX = temp[1];

            var intervalWidth:int = endX - startX;//the interval width

            if (intervalWidth >= appleWidth) {//find an available one
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public static function breakInterval(target:Array, appleWidth:int, index:int):int {
        var temp:Array = target[index];

        var startX:int = temp[0];
        var endX:int = temp[1];

        var width:int = endX - startX;

        var availableNewXRange:int = width - appleWidth;//the apple‘s max x, and the min x is startX

        //random a position
        var appleX:int = startX + availableNewXRange*Math.random();

        var leftInterval:Array = [startX, appleX];//the left interval of apple

        var rightInterval:Array = [appleX+appleWidth, endX];//the right interval of apple

        //delete temp
        target.splice(index, 1);

        if (isAvailableInterval(leftInterval, appleWidth)) {
            target.push(leftInterval);
        }

        if (isAvailableInterval(rightInterval, appleWidth)) {
            target.push(rightInterval);
        } else {
            trace("vvv");
        }

        return appleX;
    }

    private static function isAvailableInterval(interval:Array, appleWidth:int):Boolean {

        if (interval == null || interval.length < 2) {
            return false;
        }

        return (interval[1] - interval[0]) >= appleWidth;
    }
```

Put the three functions into a class A

```
        var target:Array = [[0, 1000]];
        var appWidth:int = 80;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            var index:int = A.findAvailInterval(target, appWidth);

            if (index != -1) {
                var interval:Array = target[index];

                RR.breakInterval(target, appWidth, index);

                trace(interval);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I got error when useing this: `1120: Access of undefined property mInterval.`

Comment: mInterval is  an element of t, you should find a interval each time and set it to mInterval.                                                                   mInterval  = findAvailInterval(t);                                      findAvailInterval is a function to find available interval to put in the apple.                                                              You could draw a line. and some points in paper. A interval is made up of two points. I think it will help you understand better.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, but could you show me how can i use this function correctly?

Comment: I have edit the answer and add some code. I have simply tested it, hope it help.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but now I misunderstood how to use It correct, If I paste all functions to my code, how to use them correct? I have tried `newPirmas.x = interval[0] + Math.random()*45;` instead `newPirmas.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;` but I got error: `1120: Access of undefined property interval.`